# Powershell Azure New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig breaking changes?

Tags: azure, powershell-3.0

Currently using (on Windows):

- PowerShell Edition: Desktop
- PowerShell Version: 5.1.18362.145
- Az module version: 3.1.0

I have a script with the following command:

```
$subnet_obj = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
              -Name $subnet_name `
              -AddressPrefix @( $subnet_address_prefix ) `
              -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg_obj `
              -ErrorAction Stop
```

Which results in the following warning:

```
WARNING: Breaking changes in the cmdlet 'New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig' :
WARNING:  - Update Property Name

WARNING: Cmdlet invocation changes :
    Old Way : -ResourceId
    New Way : -NatGatewayId
WARNING:  - Update Property Name

WARNING: Cmdlet invocation changes :
    Old Way : -InputObject
    New Way : -NatGateway
WARNING: NOTE : Go to https://aka.ms/azps-changewarnings for steps to suppress this breaking change warning, and other information on breaking changes in Azure PowerShell.
```

What I find confusing, is my command did NOT make use of the -ResourceId or -InputObject parameters, nor can I find any documentation regarding the "New Way".

So what do most do in these cases?  From what I understand if I suppress the warning, I can only suppress ALL warnings; which isn't exactly great.

Or... Does one just ignore these until something actually breaks and/or some documentation surfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore them, although there is no doc currently, Azure should release a new service whose resource type is `Microsoft.Network/natGateways` in the future.

There are [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/New-AzNatGateway?view=azps-3.1.0), [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/natgateways/createorupdate), [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nat/gateway?view=azure-cli-latest) about this resource, but you could not use them, the latest `api-version=2019-09-01` is not supported.

The old `-ResourceId` and `-InputObject` are just the Aliases of the  `-NatGatewayId` and `-NatGateway`.

[image: NatGatewayId]

[image]

[Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-azvirtualnetworksubnetconfig?view=azps-3.1.0#examples) of the usage:(it is not supported currently)

```
$natgateway = New-AzNatGateway -ResourceGroupName "natgateway_test" -Name "nat_gateway" `
   -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4 -Sku "Standard" -Location "eastus2" -PublicIpAddress $pip

$natGatewaySubnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name natGatewaySubnet `
   -AddressPrefix "10.0.3.0/24" -InputObject $natGateway
```

Comment: Thanks @joy-wang -- will ignore for now.  So are "Nat" gateways going to replace VirtualNetworks per se -- is that what is coming down the pipe?

Comment: @bdcoder I am not sure currently, we may have to wait for its official release.

Answer (score 0):

it warns you whenever you use that cmdlet, so you should not be worried if you are not using those particular parameters.

> From what I understand if I suppress the warning, I can only suppress
>   ALL warnings; which isn't exactly great.

that is true.